# Python Module Not Found Error when importing package

Tags: python, import

I am creating a Python Function App cherry-picking code from Ultralytics Yolov5.

The folder structure looks like this (simplified)

```
Function
|_ ApiCall
|  |_ __init__.py
|     function.json
|_Lib/site-packages
|  |_ ultralytics
|     |_ yolo
|     |  |_ utils
|     |  |  __init__.py
|     |  |  checks.py
|     |  |_ __init__.py
|     |_ __init__.py
|_ utils
|  __init__.py
|  general.py
|_ detect.py
```

Inside the detect.py file there is an import

```
from utils.general import (Profile, check_file, check_img_size, non_max_suppression, scale_boxes)
```

In general.py

```
from ultralytics.yolo.utils.checks import check_requirements
```

This seems to be where the error is coming from. The error is shown below

```
Result: Failure
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ultralytics.yolo'. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module. For more info, please refer the troubleshooting guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? According to all the articles I've read, I need to have an **init**.py file in each folder to mark it as a package so that I can import it like any other module. I'm running this in a venv with the following requirements.txt

```
azure-functions
gitpython>=3.1.30
matplotlib>=3.3
numpy>=1.26.0
shapely>=2.0.1
torch>=2.0.1
torchvision>=0.15.1
ultralytics>=8.0.107
pandas>=1.1.4
setuptools>=65.5.1
```

Comment: if you check the  ultralytics package, there is no yolo subfolder inside it directly . i think you are missing out something about ultralytics, tyr to ckeck the source code of the package : https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/ultralytics/utils/checks.py), looks like the `utils` package sits in `ultralytics` and not in `ultralytics.yolo`.  Therefore the correct import for checks should be

```
from ultralytics.utils.checks import check_requirements
```

Comment: This is so bizzare. The code that I pulled from the source code has the utils folder in the yolo folder, but if I remove the yolo from the import without changing anything else, it works as I would expect.

Comment: I created a pull request at the original repo for this problem.